# Apache Aries and Servlet as osgi service

Tags: servlets, osgi, apache-felix, aries

I am trying to use apache aries for dependency injection in an osgi bundle.
This bundle has a servlet which is registered as a service in the bundle activator.
How do we configure the servlet as a bean and/or service in the blueprint config xml?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0
       http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd">

<bean id="whiteBoardServlet" class="org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.samples.whiteboard.internal.WhiteboardServlet">
    <argument type="java.lang.String" value="/whiteboard"/>
</bean>
<service id="whiteBoardServletService" ref="whiteBoardServlet" interface="javax.servlet.Servlet">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="alias" value="/whiteboard"/>
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

More details can be found at the [Pax Web Samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/whiteboard-blueprint).